# How does find -execdir <command> + work?

Tags: find, parallelism

I understand that `find -tests -execdir <command> '{}' ';'` runs `command` for every matching file against the test(s) specified. The command, when using `-execdir`, is executed in the same parent directory as the matching file (for every matching file), as `{}` stands for the basename of the matching file.

Now the question is: how is this done when working with multiple files all at once using `+` instead of `';'`? If I use `find -tests -execdir <command> '{}' +`, all of the files are supplied as arguments to the command specified (in a manner that doesn't exceed max args). How does find carry out `<command>` on all of them at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say your `find` locates the following files:

```
./foo/bar
./foo/baz
./foo/quux
```

If you use `-execdir [...]+`, the effective resultant command will be:

```
( cd ./foo; command bar baz quux )
```

As opposed to (effectively) this, if you use `-execdir [...] \;`:

```
( cd ./foo; command bar )
( cd ./foo; command baz )
( cd ./foo; command quux )
```

The same is true for `-exec` rather than `execdir`, but it will specify the path rather than changing the working directory.  If you use `-exec [...]+`, the effective resultant command will be:

```
command ./foo/bar ./foo/baz ./foo/quux
```

As opposed to (effectively) this, if you use `-exec [...] \;`:

```
command ./foo/bar
command ./foo/baz
command ./foo/quux
```

Let's see how this behaves with files found in two directories:

```
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   ├── bletch
│   └── freeble
└── foo
    ├── bar
    ├── baz
    └── quux
$ find . -type f -exec echo {} \;
./foo/baz
./foo/quux
./foo/bar
./bar/bletch
./bar/freeble
$ find . -type f -execdir echo {} \;
./baz
./quux
./bar
./bletch
./freeble
$ find . -type f -exec echo {} +
./foo/baz ./foo/quux ./foo/bar ./bar/bletch ./bar/freeble
$ find . -type f -execdir echo {} +
./baz ./quux ./bar
./bletch ./freeble
```

Comment: So you are saying it kinda sorts and uniquifies the directories which it should cd to and performs the command per directory?

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Comment: Interesting! Did you figure this out yourself or do have some sort of reference?

Comment: A combination of tilting my head wile squinting at the output of `man find` and a healthy amount of experimentation.

Comment: But this doesn't seem to be always the case. I tried the example you provided and it did work as you explained. However, I experimented with another tree of directories and files. The behavior was a bit different. `-execdir echo '{}' +` did collect the files of a directory in a single run but for another directory, files found were processed individually.

Comment: I submitted a bug here: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?54860

Comment: It's not really a bug; there's nothing in the requirements that says all files must be processed with one exec command call.  It may easily depend on the order the files and directories are read by `readdir()`