# execute a command recursively on the files of a folder in the matching location, not in the original one

Tags: bash, find, for, exec

I want to recursively convert files from `.docx` to `.doc` in a folder. The problem is that all the output files are created in the folder where I run the following command, not in the location of the source files:

```
find -type f -name "*.docx"-exec libreoffice --convert-to doc {} \;
```

I understand that find gives source files to the `libreoffice` command and the output obviously has to be in the current location, so how can I use a command to loop recursively into a folder and execute the command from the location where the files is found, not the initial one?

Comment: Try `-execdir` instead of -exec. Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476126/how-does-find-execdir-command-work)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `-execdir` is for, if your `find` supports it. The default find on Linux systems, GNU `find`, does have it. From `man find`:

> -execdir command ;
>
> -execdir command {} +
>
> Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not
> normally  the  directory in which you started find.  [ . . . ]

So you want:

```
find . -type f -name "*.docx" -execdir libreoffice --convert-to doc {} \;
```

The file name will be inserted at each instance of `{}`. If `-exec` is used, `{}` will include the relative path starting with `./`. If `-execdir` is used, `{}` will only be the file name.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass the find output to a shell command to do this.

```
find . -type f -name \*.docx -exec sh -c 'echo libreoffice --convert-to-doc {} --outdir $(dirname {})' \;
```

The suggestion in comment from @EdgarMagallon is actually simpler than mine. Certainly, for this use case I would suggest his command.

Comment: Pass the pathname as an argument to the `sh -c` script, don't inject it into the script text (would cause issues if the pathnames contain quotes or other characters that are special to the shell; a file called `$(sudo reboot).docx` could cause havoc, for example).

Answer (score 0):

With `-execdir` instead of `-exec` the problem is solved:

```
find . -type f -name "*.docx" -execdir libreoffice --convert-to doc {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `--output-dir` or change the directory to the directory where the document was found.  Below, I show how this may be done without using the non-standard (but commonly implemented) `-execdir` predicate of `find`.

This passes the pathnames of the found files to a short in-line script that iterates over them.  For each found name, the script changes to the directory where the file was found and then converts it there.  The `cd` is carried out in a subshell, so the environment for the rest of the script is not affected.

```bash
find . -name '*.docx' -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        ( cd "$(dirname "$pathname")" && libreoffice --convert-to doc "$(basename "$pathname")" )
    done' sh {} +
```

The following is similar but does not change the working directory. Instead, it uses the `--outdir` option to specify the directory path where to write the converted document.

```bash
find . -name '*.docx' -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        libreoffice \
            --convert-to doc "$pathname" \
            --outdir "$(dirname "$pathname")"
    done' sh {} +
```

In the shell code above, `"$(dirname "$pathname")"` may be replaced by `"${pathname%/*}"` (`"$pathname"` with the shortest suffix string matching `/*` removed) while `"$(basename "$pathname")"` may be replaced by `"${pathname##*/}"` (`"$pathname"` with the longest prefix string matching `*/` removed).